# YUI Compressor java

Tags: java

I want to use Yahoo's compressor for compressing js and css files.

Which can be found here:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

My only problem is that i have never used Java before. I have no idea how to execute or use this command line. I only have experience with js, jquery and php.

It simply says:

Usage:

```
java -jar yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar [options] [input file]
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Have you even *attempted* executing that command on your command line?

Comment: Voting for migration because this question boils down to: `How do I start a Java application`.

Answer (score 2):

Grab yourself a copy of the Java Runtime Enviroment (JRE): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Install this, and use the java.exe that's being installed to run the program from the commandline (Windows->Run->cmd.exe [enter]) and add the parameters as described in your question.

```
C:\> java.exe -jar yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar [options] [input file]
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the Java Runtime or Java JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

If on Windows you might have to modify the environment variables and add java.exe to your path.

After that, download the yuicompressor and place the file you want to compress in the same directory.

To compress a file A.js and save the compressed file as A.compressed.js (or css if you like)

```
C:\>java -jar yuicompressor-x.jar -o A.js A.compressed.js
```

If the -o option is not provided the output will be the standard output (probably your console).

To get help run

```
C:\>java -jar yuicompressor-x.jar --help (or execute with no options)
```